# Google CalendarV3 Event date format - error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-api, google-api-ruby-client

it's related to Google::Apis::CalendarV3::Event date format error

while I execute my code to add an event to a google calendar i get this error message

> invalid: Start and end times must either both be date or both be dateTime.

I tried many ways, I post you 2 of them, I can't make it work ! 
Is their any helper function in Google API consuming a 'DateTime' and returning to correct string ?

thnaks

Gregoire

```
   start = DateTime.new(2017, 12, 9, 12, 0, 0)
ende = DateTime.new(2017, 12, 9, 12, 0, 0)


event = Google::Apis::CalendarV3::Event.new(
    summary: 'test',
    description: 'desc',
    start:  { datetime: start },
    end:    { datetime: ende }
)

# event = Google::Apis::CalendarV3::Event.new(
#     summary: 'test',
#     description: 'desc',
#     start:  { datetime: start.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%l:%M:%S.000-07:00") },
#     end:    { datetime: ende.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%l:%M:%S.000-07:00") }
# )

result = calendar.insert_event('primary', event)
puts "Event created: #{result.html_link}"
```

Ps : I write software for more than 20 years now, and we still have the same date/time problems !

Answer (score 1):

Finaly the solution is :

```
date_time: start.to_datetime.rfc3339,
```